# svn problem in command line

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have installed TortoiseSVN in the C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN folder. In the Environment Variable window, I have added in the variable name *Path* the variable value *C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin*. Still when I open the command line window and type

```
svn checkout http://xxxx/xxxx --username xxxx
```

I get the usual:

```
svn is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Does anyone know hoe to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TortoiseSVN doesn't come with a `svn` executable, at least not my version.

I *think* it makes use of the client libraries in DLL form.

Get the original SVN binaries e.g. from [CollabNet](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion/). The "Command-line client" download should be what you need.

**Edit**: TortoiseSVN has command line options, too, but they differ massively from `svn`'s ones. See [Appendix D. Automating TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html)

Answer (score 3):

actually there is an option while installing TortoiseSVN, whether user would like to the command line features. Be default, it's not installed; however, sure, you can install it at will.